# Javascript doesn't work in only firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, onmouseover

I have a script that hover over a thumbnail and it will show an enlarged image. This work just fine in IE, Chrome, and Safari. But in Firefox however it is not working correctly. It will show the image, but it will not hover next to the image correctly. It will stay in an absolute location on the page and not follow the true body value. It should be in a fixed location like it is in IE or chrome.

I was wondering if there is a Mozilla or Firefox specific exception I need to add. Here is my code:

```
//  Simple Image Trail script- By JavaScriptKit.com
var offsetfrommouse = [15, 10]; //image x,y offsets from cursor position in pixels.
var myimageheight = 250;
var myimagewidth = 250;
if (document.getElementById || document.all) {
    document.write('<div id="DynPreviewPlace"></div>');
}

function gettrailobj() {
    if (document.getElementById)
        return document.getElementById("DynPreviewPlace").style
    else if (document.all)
        return document.all.DynPreviewPlace.style
}

function gettrailobjnostyle() {
    if (document.getElementById)
        return document.getElementById("DynPreviewPlace")
    else if (document.all)
        return document.all.DynPreviewPlace
}

function truebody() {
    if (window.getComputedStyle && !window.globalStorage && !window.opera) {
        return (!window.chrome && window.getComputedStyle && document.compatMode != "CSS1Compat") ? document.documentElement : document.body
    } else if () {} else {
        return (!window.chrome && document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat") ? document.documentElement : document.body
    }
}

function showtrail(imagename, title, width, height) {
    document.onmousemove = followmouse;
    (height == 0) ? height = myimageheight : '';
    width += 15
    height += 30
    myimageheight = height
    myimagewidth = width
    newHTML = '<div class="DynPreviewWraper" style="width:' + width + 'px;"><div id="DynPreviewContainer"><div class="DynPreviewLoader"><div align="center">Loading preview...</div><div class="DynPreviewLoaderBg"><div id="DynProgress"> </div></div></div></div>';
    newHTML = newHTML + '<h2 class="DynPreviewTitle">' + ' ' + title + '</h2>'
    newHTML = newHTML + '<img onload="javascript:remove_loading();" src="' + imagename + '" class="DynPreviewTempLoad" alt="" />';
    newHTML = newHTML + '<!--[if lte IE 6.5]><iframe></iframe><![endif]--></div>';
    gettrailobjnostyle().innerHTML = newHTML;
    gettrailobj().display = "block";

}

function hidetrail() {
    gettrailobj().innerHTML = " ";
    gettrailobj().display = "none"
    document.onmousemove = ""
    gettrailobj().left = "-500px"
}

function followmouse(e) {
    var xcoord = offsetfrommouse[0]
    var ycoord = offsetfrommouse[1]
    var docwidth = document.all ? truebody().scrollLeft + truebody().clientWidth : pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - 15
    var docheight = document.all ? Math.min(truebody().scrollHeight, truebody().clientHeight) : Math.min(window.innerHeight)
    if (typeof e != "undefined") {
        if (docwidth - e.pageX < myimagewidth + 2 * offsetfrommouse[0]) {
            xcoord = e.pageX - xcoord - myimagewidth;
        } else {
            xcoord += e.pageX;
        }
        if (docheight - e.pageY < (myimageheight + 110)) {
            ycoord += e.pageY - Math.max(0, (110 + myimageheight + e.pageY - docheight - truebody().scrollTop));
        } else {
            ycoord += e.pageY;
        }
    } else if (typeof window.event != "undefined") {
        if (docwidth - event.clientX < myimagewidth + 2 * offsetfrommouse[0]) {
            xcoord = event.clientX + truebody().scrollLeft - xcoord - myimagewidth;
        } else {
            xcoord += truebody().scrollLeft + event.clientX
        }
        if (docheight - event.clientY < (myimageheight + 110)) {
            ycoord += event.clientY + truebody().scrollTop - Math.max(0, (110 + myimageheight + event.clientY - docheight));
        } else {
            ycoord += truebody().scrollTop + event.clientY;
        }
    }
    var docwidth = document.all ? truebody().scrollLeft + truebody().clientWidth : pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - 15
    var docheight = document.all ? Math.max(truebody().scrollHeight, truebody().clientHeight) : Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, window.innerHeight)
    if (ycoord < 0) {
        ycoord = ycoord * -1;
    }
    gettrailobj().left = xcoord + 'px';
    gettrailobj().top = ycoord + 'px';
}
var t_id = setInterval(animate, 20);
var pos = 0;
var dir = 2;
var len = 0;

function animate() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('DynProgress');
    if (elem != null) {
        if (pos == 0) len += dir;
        if (len > 32 || pos > 79) pos += dir;
        if (pos > 79) len -= dir;
        if (pos > 79 && len == 0) pos = 0;
    }
}

function remove_loading() {
    this.clearInterval(t_id);
    var targelem = document.getElementById('DynPreviewContainer');
    targelem.style.display = 'none';
    targelem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    var t_id = setInterval(animate, 60);
}
```

This is driving me crazy. I have been trying everything. You can see a page that the problem is at here: https://www.woodenduckshoppe.com/shoppe/christmas-decorations/

Comment: If you had to add an extension, so would all your users. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: The enlarged images work fine for me in FireFox.

Comment: Same here. I do get an error, though: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://www.woodenduckshoppe.com/shoppe/skin/woodenduck-mod/images/2column/list_dialog_bg_left.gif"

Comment: I just edited my entry. The images show up, just they will not stay next to the image if you scroll down the page. Try it in IE or chrome.

Comment: It is not accounting for the page scroll. That would be your problem.

Comment: No console errors. I didn't write this script, just told to fix it. I have been racking my brain on this and need some community help. This issue only appeared because of some FF updates, it didn't have it supposedly 6 months ago.

Comment: yeah I can see that it isn't accounting for the page scroll, but how to fix it, that is the problem.

Comment: I think I have to add something to the function truebody, I just don't know what. I was thinking an if statement saying if the window is Firefox use this compatmode, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Or it could be in the docheight variable line:
    var docheight=document.all? Math.min(truebody().scrollHeight, truebody().clientHeight) : Math.min(window.innerHeight)

Comment: If you look at the page in firebug, there is a style being placed in the div that the hover is placed into. The style is what is determining the distance from the top of the page.

Comment: Your `truebody` function is running different code in different browsers.  Have you tried not doing that?

Answer (score 0):

> Your truebody function is running different code in different
>   browsers. Have you tried not doing that? – Boris Zbarsky 15 hours ago

I have been trying to figure out what to write there. I just don't know what to put for just firefox/mozilla. That is the only browser having the problem.

I see that the truebody isn't being read in Firefox, I just don't know why or how to fix it.

Comment: Well I went ahead and decided to just rewrite the whole thing in jquery. It will just be easier and the end-life will be longer.